# Getting "Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined" while using Array.filter() in angular template

Tags: angular

I am getting above mentioned error while using `Array.filter` in my angular template. However, if I create a `pipe` to filter the array, it works fine.

**Code which throws error:** `Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined`

```
<div *ngFor="let i of ([0,1,2,3,5].filter((val)=>val>2))"></div>
```

[STACKBLITZ LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxnrdm)

**Code which works fine:**

```
<div *ngFor="let i of ([0,1,2,3,5]|filterArray)">{{i}}</div>
```

filter array pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterArray'
})
export class FilterArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(arr: [any], args?: any): any {
    return arr.filter((val)=>val>=3);
  }

}
```

---

**Full Error:**

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("


<div [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let i of ([0,1,2,3,5].filter((val)=>val>2))"></div>
<!--<div *ngFor="let i of ([0,1,2,3,5]|f"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@3:5
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:215)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14702)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:22709)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:22696)
    at compiler.js:22639
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:22639)
    at compiler.js:22549
    at Object.then (compiler.js:206)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:22548)
syntaxError @ compiler.js:215
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse @ compiler.js:14702
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate @ compiler.js:22709
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate @ compiler.js:22696
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:22639
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents @ compiler.js:22639
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:22549
then @ compiler.js:206
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:22548
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:22508
push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:143
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4182
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

Comment: can you post the template, as i see nowhere you are calling toUpperCase

Comment: Exactly! This error is not helpful. That is the entire code, there is nothing else in template or in project.

Comment: added stackblitz link

Comment: I'm pretty sure you may not define [arrow] functions in Angular expressions.

Comment: Arrow function wont work on your html template as those are derived from cofeescript which is again not template driven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generic error thrown by Angular which comes from Angular itself whenever template has some issue.

In this case you are trying to use an arrow function of filter in the template itself,which is wrong.

Also, It's not a wise idea to do this in the first place. Every time change detection runs, this filter call will be re-executed which will have a huge performance issue. So i would ask you to filter the items in component.ts and bind it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])">
  <p *ngIf="item> 2">
      {{item}}
  </p>
</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kg18qk)